# Is there a way to let an object to call a function after calling certain function?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm to develop PHP and I'm curious about that calling a function limits itself before calling certain function with auto-complete.

Here is the codes below I want to do.

```
$this->Order = new Order();
$this->Order->setProductDetail()->setOrderDetail()->sendPayment();
```

So the `sendPayment()` function should be the last to be called.
and `setProductDetail()` & `setOrderDetail()` functions should be prior than `sendPayment()`.

Therefore this code is invalid.

```
$this->Order->sendPayment()->setProductDetail()->setOrderDetail();
```

Is it possible for PhpStorm to do this with auto-complete?

Comment: The only way is to declare `sendPayment()` as function that returns nothing (e.g. `@return void` in PHPDoc for that function). Other than that -- *that's up to developer to use methods in the right order*. If it's hard to remember the right sequence (for whatever reason -- e.g. this API will be used by junior devs/3rd party and they do not always read the docs etc) .. then better create one more easy-to-use method that will do that in one go (not ideal solution, but might work if there is no many parameters).

Comment: You could make those methods private and call another method which runs them in the right order? i.e. `$this->order->process();` which just does the code you added above...

Comment: But to answer your question: there is no functionality in PhpStorm that would check the order of calling methods. If all methods follow fluid interface (`return $this`) then from IDE point of view any sequence is perfectly valid.

Comment: hmm. alright then. Thank you for letting me know that there is no such a functionality. Understanding the fact is helpful for me. Thanks!!